# French keyboard for MacBook

Tags: keyboard

I haven’t been able to get a French keyboard in Australia  and I’m now in Singapore. Other than the US or Europe, is there anywhere I can get a MacBook with a French physical keyboard in the region? Thank you.

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the online stores in whatever countries you are willing to travel to. When you pretend to buy something, the sites will tell you what keyboards are available.  Apple stores do not ship outside their own country.  The other option would be to buy from a non-Apple source.